# How to rollback database changes during Flask testing

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, pytest

When running tests in pytest, the database is modified. What is the best way to undo changes to the database?

### DBSession rollback

For those tests where I can access the backend directly, I currently use pytest fixture to start a new DBSession for every test function, and rollback the session at the end of it

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def db(app, request):
    """Session-wide test database."""
    def teardown():
        pass

    _db = SQLAlchemy(app)    
    return _db

@pytest.fixture(scope='function')
def db_session(db, request):
    """Creates a new database session for a test."""
    engine = create_engine(
                            TestConfig.SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI,
                            connect_args={"options": "-c timezone=utc"})
    DbSession = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
    session = DbSession()
    connection = engine.connect()
    transaction = connection.begin()
    options = dict(bind=connection, binds={})
    session = db.create_scoped_session(options=options)
    db.session = session

    yield session

    transaction.rollback()
    connection.close()
    session.remove()
```

In the test code, I simply use the fixture

def test_create_project(db_session):
    project = _create_test_project(db_session)
    assert project.project_id > 0

### Flask / HTTP Testing

But for testing the API via Flask/HTTP, I cannot use `db_session`. Even when I create a fixture to explicitly `DROP` the test database and restore from production, it will not work because there is no direct database code

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='function')
def db_session_refresh(db, request):
    """Refresh the test database from production after running the test"""
    engine = create_engine(
                            TestConfig.SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI,
                            connect_args={"options": "-c timezone=utc"})
    DbSession = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
    session = DbSession()

    connection = engine.connect()
    transaction = connection.begin()

    options = dict(bind=connection, binds={})
    session = db.create_scoped_session(options=options)

    db.session = session

    yield session

    transaction.rollback()
    connection.close()
    session.remove()  
    refresh_test_db_sql = """
        SELECT pg_terminate_backend(pid)
        FROM pg_stat_activity
        WHERE datname = 'appdb_test';

        DROP DATABASE appdb_test;

        CREATE DATABASE appdb_test TEMPLATE appdb;
        """
    engine.execute(refresh_test_db_sql)
```

Even if this works, it is inefficient to refresh the database for every function.

What is the proper/better way to run test that modifies the database?

Comment: For sure you should use a separate database for tests instead of rolling back the main one. You set up a database in `setUp` method and destroy in `tearDown`.

Comment: I do have `dbapp` and `dbapp_test`. How can I roll back changes to database when running Flask HTTP test code?

Answer (score 0):

as commented earlier - creation and destruction of the DB should be taken care out of you unit test and moved into a wrapper.

but to answer you question - I have the impression that you're using postgresql. try removing the database name from your connection string and connect to it directly and add it to the [search_path](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/runtime-config-client.html)